# Gdal sieve filter in python

Tags: python, gdal, sieve

I want to sieve a classified image in py, and I try to use the gdal sieve function, but it will not work:

Syntax:

> SieveFilter(Band srcBand, Band maskBand, Band dstBand, int threshold,
>   int connectedness=4, char ** options=None, GDALProgressFunc
>   callback=0, void * callback_data=None) -> int

My code:

```
gdal.SieveFilter(1 "C:/X/testX.tif",None,1 "C:/X/testX_sieved.tif",100, 8)
```

What's the error here?

Comment: What does Python say when you try to execute it?

Comment: And your code doesn't seem to match the function signature at all. The order of arguments is wrong, plus it apparently requires a couple Band objects as arguments, and you are providing some filenames instead.

Comment: The signature is showing the type of each parameter, followed by the parameter name. For a "Band" you need myds.GetRasterBand(mybandnum), for example, a GDAL band object.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a working python binding for the gdal sieve command.  I am able to run it successfully by calling it from the command line by using this:

```
import os, sys, subprocess
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\****\Scripts')
gm = os.path.join('C:\\','Users','*****','AppData','Local','conda','conda','envs','****','Scripts','gdal_sieve.py')
sieve_command = ["python", gm,'-st','10','-8','-nomask','-of','GTiff','to_be_sieved.tif','sieved.tif']
subprocess.call(sieve_command,shell=True)
```

Of course, you'll need to change some paths in the first couple lines to point to the location where your gdal scripts are stored.

Answer (score 1):

To apply the sieve in Python, you must provide raster bands for the first and third arguments. I suspect the error arises because the destination band (third argument) is not writable (i.e. you must open the destination image in read-write mode).

For example, to overwrite the original image:

```
from osgeo import gdal
Image = gdal.Open('SomeImageName.tif', 1)  # open image in read-write mode
Band = Image.GetRasterBand(1)
gdal.SieveFilter(srcBand=Band, maskBand=None, dstBand=Band, threshold=100, connectedness=8, callback=gdal.TermProgress_nocb)
del Image, Band  # close the datasets.
```

P.S. This works on Linux, gdal=3.1, python=3.9.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but since there is no accepted answer, here's a working version using gdal>=3.5

```
from osgeo_utils.gdal_sieve import gdal_sieve

gdal_sieve(
    src_filename="C:/X/testX.tif",
    dst_filename="C:/X/testX_sieved.tif",
    threshold=100,
    connectedness=8
)
```